# Data Recovery using testDisk failing!

Tags: 10.04, partitioning, hard-drive

I am trying to recover an accidentally formatted partition using testDisk,

After selecting the **partition**[pic 1] and selecting **Undeleted**[pic 1], it says, **No deleted file found.**[pic 2]

```
1
```

[image: 1]

```
2
```

[image: 2]

I know it's a silly question, but I just want to make sure that those data are really out of reach. Or is there anything I can do to recover them? :(

I tried to repair my partition table using bootrec.exe/FixMBR & bootrec.exe/FixBoot, can this be the reason why testdisk can't work anymore? I haven't written anything on that partition.

Is there any low level approach to retrieve all the lost data?

Comment: How exactly did you get those results? Here's [a detailed guide](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) on how to restore a deleted partition. Please re-try.

Comment: I started with creating a new log file, then selected the hard disk, then selected Intel, then selected "Advanced [Filesystem Utils]", then partition selection(pic 1), then selecting undelete, and finally is says, "No deleted file found".

Comment: In the tutorial, they are using, Oct 2007 version, But I am using, May 2011 version of test disk, that's why things are a little different.

Comment: Don't go to 'Advanced' but to 'Analyse' first (see link). My workflow: analyse, (deeper search if necessary), list files, if files look ok write changes. The basic steps from that guide are still valid for versions 6.11/6.12.

Comment: @htorque  The list doesn't show any file that has been formatted[ScreenShot](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e179/iamcreasy/Screenshot-3.png). It shows some rather unknown files, which may have been created for **bootrec.exe/FixMBR & bootrec.exe/FixBoot** commands.. :-s Should I try rewriting the partition table of that partition?

Comment: Can you do `Analyse` > `Quick Search` > `Deeper Search` and post a screenshot? I think it's safe to say that BootRec killed some of your files on the Linux partition. :-/

Comment: Just to be sure: you *do* have backups of the other five partitions, do you? Dealing with partition problems is always critical so don't assume anything will go right - always have a backup!

Comment: I started using, Ontrack EasyRecovery Pro and It successfully recovered some files. But, I sill want to make a image of the damaged partition. What software can I use to make image that should be widely recognizable by many recovery softwares?

Comment: Successfully retrieved around 14GB of my documentations :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `photorec` instead.

Comment: Photorec only recovers photos, but I was trying to recover my whole partition.

Comment: If you don't have a backup then you're out of luck.

Comment: Isn't there any sort of extrema low level analysis? I haven't written anything on that partition. :(

Comment: Yea... photorec.

Comment: "Photorec only recovers photos". FALSE. `PhotoRec` knows about [a great deal more than just photos](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec#Known_file_formats).

Comment: @landroni Indeed. Photorec is amazing if testdisk simply won't work. However, know that photrec will not recover your file names or directory structure.